# Категории и страницы от Woocommerce не отображаются в консоли

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Категории и страницы от Woocommerce не отображаются в консоли, внешний вид -> Меню.
Все подключение сделаны. Тему разрабатывал я сам. Стандартный шаблон для подключения woocommerce от сайта underscores.me
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в визуальной настройке есть категории от woocommerce:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Срочно помогите пожалуйста, у меня проект на сроке висит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справа вверху выберите "Настройки экрана" и в открывшихся настройках - "Категории товаров"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: KAGG Design, спасибо что вы есть) 70% ответов получаю от вас)